# Assigning int to byte in java

Tags: java

In java, it is fine to have:

```
byte b = (int) 2;
```

where java automatically convert int to byte. On the other hand, if we do:

```
int a = 2;
byte b = a;
```

this will give an error saying that the required type is byte but int is provided.

May I ask how to understand the reason why automatic conversion works when literal number of type int is assigning to a variable of type byte while it doesn't work when the literal number is replaced by a variable of type int?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's because a `byte` may be a `char` as well, and a `char` cannot be automatically converted to an `int`.

Comment: Because `a` is not a constant the compiler treats it as "any int" and therefor cannot guarantee that it fits the byte or if it isn't to big. put a final modifier in front of a (`final int a = 2;`) and **it will work**.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks I think this makes much more sense, could you please turn your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to have

```
byte b = (int) 2;
```

Because 2 is casted into int and than it is the same as

```
byte b = 2;
```

The following also works

```
int a = 2;
byte b = (byte) a;
```